# Flutter In_App_Purchase Error: Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: change require() of ES Module \node_modules\camelcase-keys\index.js to dynamic import()

Tags: node.js, flutter

I am trying to setup Flutter In_App_Purchase (The offical Flutter In_App_Purchase Package) and I run into a problem with the firebase-backend. Whenever I try to deploy it, I run into the following error:

Failed to load function definition from source: Failed to generate manifest from function source: Error
[ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module C:\Users\larak\Desktop\Fashionbook\FashionLookbook_FlutterIAP_Backend-IAP\firebase-backend\functions\node_modules\camelcase-keys\index.js from C:\Users\larak\Desktop\Fashionbook\FashionLookbook_FlutterIAP_Backend-IAP\firebase-backend\functions\lib\app-store.purchase-handler.js not supported.
Instead change the require of index.js in C:\Users\larak\Desktop\Fashionbook\FashionLookbook_FlutterIAP_Backend-IAP\firebase-backend\functions\lib\app-store.purchase-handler.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.

I think it's related to this line in app-store.purchase-handler.ts:

import camelCaseKeys from "firebase-backend/functions/scr/camelcase-keys";

Full example code here: https://github.com/flutter/codelabs/tree/master/in_app_purchases/complete/firebase-backend

I tried to change it as described in the error message, but I wasn't able to achieve it. I have zero experience with TypeScript. I'm a Flutter developer and I usually use Node.js with JavaScript.

Comment: I also have the same error, did you find any solution? please let me know if you find any solution.

Comment: Yes, you can fix it as here described: https://github.com/flutter/codelabs/pull/1250/files. The red things are the things, that should be removed from the code and the green parts are the things, that should be added. Good luck : )